# External API integration into WordPress

Tags: wordpress, api

I am working on a website that needs data from "wunderground" therefore they have issued me with an API Key, i needed to know how i integrate the API key into the existing word press site. That the main problem i am facing, or are there existing plugins to assist with this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to search for 'wunderground' on wordpress.org? First result that showed up: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wunderground/faq/

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin available:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wunderground/faq/

From the plugin page:

> **Do I need a Wunderground account?**
>
> Weather Underground has been very
> gracious and has provided the plugin with free data - you don't need
> your own account. If you want to use Wunderground data in your own
> application, register for a Weather Underground API account.